# Проблема при докеде Base64

Tags: java

```
String lol = "привет";
String dec = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(lol.getBytes());
System.out.println(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dec)));
```

На выходе получаю
???????

Comment: Попробуйте при вызове `getBytes` и `new String` явно указать кодировку *UTF-8*

Comment: Ещё может быть такое, что у вас терминал не умеет в юникод, проверьте, если просто вывести слово "привет", оно нормально выведется?

Comment: слово привет нормально выводиться, пробовал в UTF-8 результат тот же